# What is the advantage of a tensorflow.data.Dataset over a tensorflow.Tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

I have my own input data class. It has x and y as well as test and train values (1 Tensor for each combination). I noticed there is a Dataset class built in to TensorFlow. What is the advantage of this class over a regular Tensor? Is it mainly around handling large datasets / laziness? It doesn't appear to have features tailored for x vs y data, or test vs train. All my data fits into memory so I am not clear it would be beneficial to use the built in class over my current one. Of course, the first assumption is it would be foolish not to use the built in class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main advantage is in domains where you can't fit all of your data into memory.

However, I've seen improvements in performance even in cases where I have all my data into memory. I think two reasons contribute to this:

- One is [caching](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#caching), where some operations (e.g. a mapping OP) will be cached and performed only in the first epoch. This, obviously is applicable if you have such a function.
- Another one is [prefetching](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#prefetching). While a the model is being trained on a batch in the GPU, the CPU loads and prepares the next batch. This can help save a lot of time.

Some other capabilities are allowing for the [vectorization of user defined functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#vectorizing_mapping) (e.g. for data augmentation) and their [parallelization](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#parallelizing_data_transformation).

You can take a look at some benchmarks [here](https://github.com/djib2011/tensorflow-dl-tutorial/blob/master/06_datasets.ipynb). They are a bit unrelated, as they refer to cases where the dataset isn't all loaded into memory, but they might interest you nevertheless.

Comment: Great! I'll look into those features more and see if I can take advantage of them.